# Get data from mysql and then display each of them inside dynamic table with angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I have mysql database. User can enter number of fields inside input and that number is stored inside db. When user define number of fields (for example 3) new fields appears. In our example of 3 fields new 6 fields appears.

For each of 3 fields user gets 2 new fields. In 1st one he enters name and in 2nd one he enters quantity.

So he can enter for example banana 5, apple 7, orange 2.

In our db we have

num_fields: 3,

1_name: banana,

2_name: apple,

3_name: orange,

1: 5,

2: 7,

3: 2.

I made view in angularjs:

```
<table id="my_table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Fruit</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in [] |  fields:fieldsExpr">
                    <td>fruits</td>
                    <td ng-repeat="qty in qtys">{{qty}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And my js:

```
app.filter('fields', function () {
        return function (input, total) {
            total = parseInt(total);
            for (var i = 0; i < total; i++)
                input.push(i);
            return input;
        };
    });


app.controller('Fruit', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    //1st we need to get number of fields
    var numberOfFields = 'num_opts';
    $http({
        url: 'get_options.php',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: $.param({option: numberOfFields})
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        var fields = $.parseJSON(data);
        $scope.fields = extras;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(status);
    });
    //now we need to get other fields
    var fieldsLen = $scope.fields;
    $scope.qtys = [];
    for(var i=1;i<=fieldsLen;i++){
        $http({
        url: 'get_options.php',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: $.param({option: i})
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        var quantity = $.parseJSON(data);
        $scope.qtys.push(quantity);
        //array with qtys from table is retrieved successfully and we have array with '5', '7', '2'
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(status);
    });
    }
}]);
```

So I managed to get options based on user input and I managed to display rows in table based on user defined number. But I can't set numbers from array so they are displayed into table rows separately. With above code I just got printed 5,7,2 in each row.

Any tricks and tips ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made it. I will post answer so people can see it in future if anyone needs it.

First in our js we can remove angular filter. We'll show columns for each option. Then on server side we'll encode json in array. So when query is executed we'll make this:

```
echo json_encode([
    'id' => $opt_name,//we can get any data we want from server
    'qty' => $value,
    'name' => $value2
]);
```

Now in our controller:

```
app.controller('Extras', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', 'passData', 'pageContent', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, passData, pageContent) {
//1st we need to get number of fields
var numberOfFields = 'num_opts';
$http({
    url: 'get_options.php',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data: $.param({option: numberOfFields})
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    var fields = $.parseJSON(data);
    $scope.fields = fields;
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(status);
});
    var extrasLen = $scope.data.extras;
    //we define array to store data from server that we json_encode
    $scope.extras = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= extrasLen; i++) {
        $http({
            url: 'get_table_fields.php',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data: $.param({option: i})
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //we add every new data to array
            $scope.extras.push(data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(status);
        });
    }
}]);
```

Now in our view we can get data by simple `{{extra.property}}`

```
    <table id="my_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Fruit</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>State</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="extra in extras">//show rows based on extras array
                <td>{{extra.name}}</td>//we can access data from extras
                <td>{{extra.qty}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```